# mysql inserting data from one schema to another

Tags: mysql, joomla1.5, database-schema

Is there a way to insert data from a table in schema1 to a table in schema2 in mysql.

Also , I assume there will be any access/privilege issues.

My environment is Joomla using Fabrik extension, PHP, MySQL

Kindly share some tips

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does that:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table1 SELECT * FROM db1.table1;
```

- Not tested but should do the job.

If you do this as root user, you will have no permission issues.

- Backup your data first, though.

Comment: Then you just have to make sure the user you use has access to both databases. If it is not the same user, you can still do it through a oneliner shell script, if you are on linux. Just msg me back if you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can always preface the table name with the database name and as long as the user has the appropriate permission you can do:

```
insert into db1.users( first, middle, last )
select a.first, a.middle, a.last from db2.users a
```

See the following for the documentation [insert .. select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: thanks. so how do I make sure the user has required permission on all schemas?